# Combine nested objects to one level

Tags: recursion, dart, reduce

I have following class in dart

```
class PostComment {
  int id;
  int title;
  int parentCommentId;
  List<PostComment> replies;
}
```

The data that I receive from the api returns all the comments (no matter at what level) in a single array. The parentCommentId is used to point to the parent of the reply. To convert this data into a nested structure I do

```
void toNestedComments({List<PostComment> comments}) {
  comments.forEach((postComment) {
    if (postComment.parentCommentId != null) {
      PostComment parentComment = comments.firstWhere((comment) => comment.id == postComment.parentCommentId, orElse: () => null);
      parentComment.replies.add(postComment);
    }
  });

  comments.removeWhere((c) => c.parentCommentId != null);
}
```

With this code, I get the comments array in below structure.

```
Post 1
    - Post 11
    - Post 12
        - Post 121
        - Post 122
    - Post 13
Post 2
    - Post 21
        - Post 211
```

However the UI requires the data to be shown in as below.

```
Post 1
    - Post 11
    - Post 12
    - Post 121
    - Post 122
    - Post 13
Post 2
    - Post 21
    - Post 211
```

What kind of modification would you suggest to the above function to achieve the above structure?

The current code and the data structure is at https://dartpad.dartlang.org/6231828b3ea9dc1e956e87353394dae7

Comment: Use the expand method on you list of posts?

Comment: I think i need some recursive logic here, to pull the replies nested deeply and put it at level one, but I am just not able to comprehend / break down this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not completely sure about the structure of your data but I guess you could do something like this:

Extend the PostComment class like this:

```
class PostComment {
  int id;
  int title;
  int parentCommentId;
  List<PostComment> replies = [];

  Iterable<PostComment> thisAndNestedReplies() sync* {
    yield this;
    for (var reply in replies) {
      yield* reply.thisAndNestedReplies();
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can do the following (I am still using yours method to get the nested data structure):

```
toNestedComments(comments: comments);
var newList = comments
    .where((postComment) => postComment.parentCommentId == null)
    .expand((postComment) => postComment.thisAndNestedReplies()).toList();
```

Comment: maybe i was not clear with the data structure, I have posted a working sample here https://dartpad.dartlang.org/6231828b3ea9dc1e956e87353394dae7

Comment: Is this better? https://gist.github.com/julemand101/b076ff080fafb535346b789944fe8057

Comment: thisAndNestedReplies() does the job. Thanks a lot. With slight modification, to my code I was able to meet the requirements. thanks a lot.